# Visual Basic: Multiplying strings/SendKeys?

Tags: vba

Ok, so I've got something like this:

```
SendKeys.send("blah" + "{BS}")
```

and I want to backspace "{BS}" multiple times, eg have a variable that I could multiply "{BS}" by to have is backspace a certain amount of times, how would I go about doing this?

I know that its possible to do in Python simply by: `"string" * variable`, just not sure how to do in VBA.

Comment: In Excel's VBA, you can use [`WorksheetFunction.Rept(string, double)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.rept.aspx).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Sending the same [key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx) several times, You try by appending a number inside the brackets

```
Application.SendKeys "{BS 6}
```